# How do I convert date result to month name?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

Noob here.. apologies for such a basic question.

I use `datename(month, date)` in SQL Server but can't find/figure out how to do the same in Alation.

Example:

```
select datename(month, '1-1-2023')
from myTable
```

Result: "January"

I've tried:

```
format(date, month)
format(date, mm)
format(date, M)
format(date, 'month')
format(date, 'mm')
format(date, 'M')
cast(date as month)
cast(date as mm)
cast(date as M)
cast(date as 'month')
cast(date as 'mm')
cast(date as 'M')
datename(month,date)
```

and other variations... but I'm still stuck!

Comment: 4 space indentation retains text unformatted, like code.

Comment: Are you referring to this [Alation](https://www.alation.com/) ?

Comment: If you must use format()  try  Select format(date,'MMMM')

Comment: Yes, this is referring to Alation.com. Tried format(date, 'MMMM' and got the same error.

"ERROR: function format(date, "unknown") does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts."